# C# batch processing of async web responses hangs just before finishing

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, concurrency, batch-processing

### *Here is the scenario.*

I want to call 2 versions of an API (hosted on different servers), then cast their responses (they come as a JSON) to C# objects and compare them.

**An important note** here is that i need to query the APIs a lot of times ~3000. The reason for this is that I query an endpoint that has an id and that returns a specific object from the DB. So my queries are like `http://myapi/v1/endpoint/id.` And I basically use a loop to go through all of the ids.

### *Here is the issue*

I start querying the API and for the first 90% of all requests it is blazing fast (I get the response and i process it) and all that happens under 5 seconds.

Then however, I start to come to a stop. The next 50-100 requests can take between 1 - 5 seconds to process and after that I come to a stop. No CPU-usage, network activity is low (and I am pretty sure that activity is from other apps). And my app just hangs.

UPDATE: Around 50% of the times I tested this, it does finally resume after quite a bit of time. But the other 50% it still just hangs

### *Here is what I am doing in-code*

I have a list of Ids that I iterate to query the endpoint.
This is the main piece of code that queries the APIs and processes the responses.

```
var endPointIds = await GetIds(); // this queries a different endpoint to get all ids, however there are no issues with it

var tasks = endPointIds.Select(async id =>
{
    var response1 = await _data.GetData($"{Consts.ApiEndpoint1}/{id}");
    var response2 = await _data.GetData($"{Consts.ApiEndpoint2}/{id}");

    return ProcessResponces(response1, response2);
});

var res = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var result = res.Where(r => r != null).ToList();

return result; // I never get to return the result, the app hangs before this is reached
```

This is the GetData() method

```
private async Task<string> GetAsync(string serviceUri)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(serviceUri);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I would link the `ProcessResponces` method as well, however I tried mocking it to return a string like so:

```
private string ProcessResponces(string responseJson1, string responseJson1)
{
    //usually i would have 2 lines that deserialize responseJson1 and responseJson1 here using Newtonsoft.Json's DeserializeObject<>
    return "Fake success";
}
```

And even with this implementation my issue did not go away (only difference it made is that I managed the have fast requests for like 97% of my requests, but my code still ended up stopping at the last few request), so I am guessing the main issue is not related to that method. But what it more or less does is deserialize both responses to c# objects, compares them and returns information about their equality.

### *Here are my observations after 4 hours of debugging*

- If I manually reduce the number of queries to my API (I used .Take() method on the list of ids) the issue still persists. For example on 1000 total requests I start hanging around 900th, for 1500 on the 1400th an so on.  I believe the issue goes away at around 100-200 requests, but I am not sure since it might just be too fast for me to notice.
- Since this is currently a console app I tried adding WriteLines() in some of my methods, and the issue seemed to go away (I am guessing the delay in speed that writing on the console creates, gives some time between requests and that helps)
- Lastly i did a concurrency profiling of my app and it reported that there were a lot of contentions happening at the point where my app hangs. Opening the *contention* tab showed that they are mainly happening with `System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()`

### *Thoughts and Questions*

- Obviously, what can I do to resolve the issue?
- Is my GetAsync() method wrong, should I be using something else instead of responseStream and streamReader?
- I am not super proficient in asynchronous operations, maybe my flow of async/await operations is wrong.
- Lastly, could it be something with the API controllers themselves? They are standard ASP.NET MVC 5 WebAPI controllers (version 5.2.3.0)

Comment: Could it be that the server you're requesting (data from the api) from is blocking or delaying your requests? I can imagine that if you are sending requests to a server 1000+ times the server will block incoming requests, or at least have difficulty processing that many in such a short time.

Comment: Also, are the API's written by you? If so, you could rewrite the API endpoint so that you can send a **list of IDs** and receive a **list of the data** back, so that you don't have to perform so many requests?

Comment: The second option could be a solution, but it is not feasible atm since the api logic is quite large and would take a lot of time to rewrite.

As far as blocking - yes it could be, but then why do I still get the issue even if i do like 300 requests.

Comment: Could you try going to the endpoint inside your browser while you are running this task in code? So that we can verify that it's not your IP that's being blocked from the server (i.e. if you can still manually go to the endpoint and get a result while the code is running, the server is not the issue, but something in the code is).

Comment: Good suggestion .. i will try it and report back

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue. Tried making a get request to the api via postman, got the response immediately

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of tracking my requests with Fiddler and finally mocking my DataProvider (_data) to retrieve locally, from disk - it turns out that I had responses that were taking 30s+ to come (or even not coming at all).

Since my `.Select()` is `async` it always dispalyed info for the quick responses first, and then came to a halt as it was waiting for the slow ones. This gave an illusion that I was somehow loading the **first X amount of requests** quickly and then stopping. When, in reality, I was simply shown the **fastest X amount of requests** and then coming to a halt as I was waiting for the slow ones.

And to kind of answer my questions...

- What can I do to resolve the issue - set a timeout that allows a maximum number of milliseconds/seconds for a request to finish.
- The GetAsync() method is alright.
- Async/await operations are also correct, just need to have in mind that doign an async select will return results ordered by the time it took for them to finish.
- The ASP.NET Framework controllers are perfectly fine and do not contribute to the issue.